# UPDATE based on multiple overlapping conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which essentially transfers a job from one worker to another.

The query works fine, but I need to add one additional check:

- ensure the **current** job owner (in `jobs`) is the worker matching `@owner` and `@teamId`.

This is essentially the condition that I need to add:

```
...
AND jobs.owner = (SELECT userId FROM workers
                     WHERE workers.id = @ownerId and workers.teamId = @teamId)
...
```

To the query below:

```
UPDATE jobs
SET owner = workers.userId,
    role = @role
FROM workers
WHERE 
      workers.id = @newOwnerId
  AND workers.teamId = @teamId
  AND jobs.id = @jobId
  AND jobs.owningTeamId = @teamId
```

The problem is that if I add that additional check, it breaks the update since I am already filtering the `workers` table by the statement `workers.id = @newOwnerId` which is necessary to `SET` the new `owner` in `jobs` table. I think I might need a double join onto that table, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is this really postgres? As there's no `@` in postgres.

Comment: it is postgres database but I am interacting via a library (sorry should have specified!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
UPDATE jobs j
SET owner = w.userId,
    role = @role
FROM workers w
WHERE w.id = @newOwnerId AND
      w.teamId = @teamId AND
      j.id = @jobId AND
      j.owningTeamId = @teamId AND
      j.owner = (SELECT w2.userId
                 FROM workers w2
                 WHERE w2.id = @ownerId and w2.teamId = @teamId
                );
```

This appears to be what you are asking for.

Comment: Yup that's the one - just had to change `w.owner` to `j.owner` (it was my fault, I've now corrected the question) and it now does what I need it to - thanks!